# A simple equivalence relation problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

For the set of all subsets of R, let $A \sim B$ mean that $A \subseteq B$ ($A$ is a subset of $B$).
Question: Is this an equivalence relation? If not explain why.

Attempt at solution: 
Reflexive- If $A \sim A$, then $A \subseteq A$.
Symmetric- If $A \sim B$ and $B \sim A$, then $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.
Transitive- If $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C$, then $A \subseteq C$.
Therefore this is an equivalence relation (not a perfect solution, I just want to get the concept right).

I know this probably should be obvious, but I feel that I'm incorrect so I thought of a simple counter-example:

If $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$, $C = \{1,2,3,4\}$. Obviously reflexive and transitive, but its definitely not symmetric.

I guess what I'm wondering is this a legitimate counter-example for this problem and does this make my solution incorrect?

Comment: You don't need $C$, but other than that yes it is a legitimate counterexample.  Your solution is wrong because you have not correctly understood the meaning of "symmetric".  To say that $\sim$ is symmetric does not mean $A\sim B$ and $B\sim A$ as you stated, but rather: "for all $A,B$, **if** $A\sim B$ **then** $B\sim A$".

Comment: I completely overlooked that, thank you. So A~B implies that B~A , which is false in this example. Hmm... now I'm considering if my transitive statement is wrong.

Comment: Your statement of transitive is slightly wrong but I'm not sure if it's a "real" error or just a typo.  Saying $\sim$ is transitive means: "for all $A,B,C$, if $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$ then $A\sim C$".  In this problem that means "for all $A,B,C$, if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then $A\subseteq C$".  You have slightly mixed up the general case and the specific example.

Comment: Got it now. It was lazily written and I should have been more careful. Thank you very much for your helpfulness and patience.

Comment: You're welcome!